# How to convert image into bit plane in android?

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, android-support-library

I have a project in an android platform that the process should force me to convert image into bit-plane, but I don't know how is the code.

The images are from gallery and taken from camera.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean with "bit-plane"? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
String encoded = Base64.encodeFromFile("data/inputImage.png");

            //Convert String data to binary image file
            Base64.decodeToFile(encoded, "data/outputImage.png");

            //Convert binary image file to byte array to base64 encoded string
            FileInputStream mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream("data/inputImage.png");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = mFileInputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
               bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            byte[] ba = bos.toByteArray();
            encoded = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

            //Convert String data to binary image file
            Base64.decodeToFile(encoded, "data/outputImage.png");

            //Convert binary image file to base64 encoded String data file
            Base64.encodeFileToFile("data/inputImage.png","data/encodedImage.txt");

            //Convert base64 encoded String data file to binary image file
            Base64.decodeFileToFile("data/encodedImage.txt","data/outputImage.png");
```

Source http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/07/convert-image-to-string-and-string-to.html

Comment: so, those code I paste in EncryptButton or is there any option?

Comment: the code that I paste to my program got error at encodeFromFile, decodeToFile, read, and encodeBytes. all of them are red.

Comment: This is the perfect code. i thing you can't get your image path. Base64.encodeFromFile(your image path); The image you want to convert has a image path.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html    and you can download free source code from here   http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample

Comment: where should I paste the code actually? after protected void OnCreate, right?

Comment: yes the problem is my image path, I dont know where is the path of gallery

Comment: Just try this [link](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample)