# add image in sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i have a problem when inserting an android image in my datatabase for a quizz application.The questions must appear with a specific image,i trie to do as someone explained me here but i have an error in my method where i add the questions.I inserted the image like this.

This my database

```
package com.example.toureamidou.piste;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by TOURE Amidou on 24/02/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Question";
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer";
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta";
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb";
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc";
    private static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT,"+KEY_IMAGE+"TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();
    }





    private void addQuestions() {
        Questions q1=new Questions("FFFFF","Tata", "Titi", "Toto", "Tata");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Questions q2=new Questions("Quel est le plus grand pays au monde", "Suisse", "Italie", "Chine", "Chine");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Questions q3=new Questions("Comment s'appele le président francais","Obama", "Hollande","Gorbatchev", "Hollande" );
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Questions q4=new Questions("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", "ali", "dede", "home","dede");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Questions q5=new Questions(" est l'homme le plus riche au monde","Gates","Trump","Carlos Slim","Trump");
        this.addQuestion(q5);

    }






    private void addQuestion(Questions quest,byte[] image) {
        Log.d("addQuestions", quest.toString());
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        values.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public List<Questions> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Questions> quesList = new ArrayList<Questions>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Questions quest = new Questions();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return quesList;
    }
    public int updateQuestions (Questions questions){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("questions",questions.getQUESTION());
        contentValues.put("answer",questions.getANSWER());
        contentValues.put("opta", questions.getOPTA());
        contentValues.put("optb", questions.getOPTB());
        contentValues.put("optc", questions.getOPTC());
        int i = db.update(TABLE_QUEST, contentValues, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(questions.getID())});
        db.close();
        return i;

    }

}

and this is my quizz activity class


package com.example.toureamidou.piste;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
public class Quiz extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Questions> quesList;
    int qid=0;
    Questions currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
    Button butNext;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    MediaPlayer wrongsound;
    MediaPlayer winsound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        quesList = myDb.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        wrongsound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mywrong);
        winsound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mysound);
        setQuestionsView();

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.quizz);
        ByteArrayOutputStream boss = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,boss);
        byte[] img = boss.toByteArray();


        butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup grp = (RadioGroup) Quiz.this.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
                RadioButton answer = (RadioButton) Quiz.this.findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Log.d("your answer", Quiz.this.currentQ.getANSWER() + " " + answer.getText());
                if (Quiz.this.currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())) {

                    winsound.start();
                } else {
                    wrongsound.start();
                }

                if (Quiz.this.qid < 5) {
                    Quiz.this.currentQ = (Questions) Quiz.this.quesList.get(Quiz.this.qid);
                    Quiz.this.setQuestionsView();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Quiz.this, Result.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();

                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    Quiz.this.startActivity(intent);
                    Quiz.this.finish();
                }

            }
        });



    }



    private void setQuestionsView() {
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
        qid++;                                


    }







}
```

Comment: Bloating your database with images (or any other heavy data) is never a good idea. You better store the image locations and load the images from there, instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to store image in sqlite database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357668/how-to-store-image-in-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the image into base64 and store the image in DB as string

Follow this code to convert your image into base64 and vice versa

[How to convert a image into Base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830711/how-to-convert-a-image-into-base64-string)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this way:

If you want to store image in **byte array** form than **Image column** must be in `BLOB` form.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase=db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT,"+KEY_IMAGE+" BLOB)";
     db.execSQL(sql);
     addQuestions();
 }
```

**Note:** Uninstall current application and run again.

Hope this will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Convert Image to Base64 String then save it in your database.

When you use get data from database. Then convert string to Base64 Image.

The process is in my answer below link

[How to convert image into bit plane in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692494/how-to-convert-image-into-bit-plane-in-android/35692802#35692802)